# What does the * [asterisk] signify in bower.json?

Tags: bower

Does it signify latest commit OR latest release OR latest tag ?

I tried looking for answer in bower docs.

Answer (score 3):

Bower is using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) (semver) for its version numbers.
The asterisk (*) is used for *X-Ranges*, which are defined as (quoted from [node-semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#x-ranges-12x-1x-12-)):

**X-Ranges**

Any of X, x, or * may be used to "stand in" for one of the numeric values in the [major, minor, patch] tuple.

```
* := >=0.0.0 (Any version satisfies)
1.x := >=1.0.0 <2.0.0 (Matching major version)
1.2.x := >=1.2.0 <1.3.0 (Matching major and minor versions)
```

A partial version range is treated as an X-Range, so the special character is in fact optional.

```
"" (empty string) := * := >=0.0.0
1 := 1.x.x := >=1.0.0 <2.0.0
1.2 := 1.2.x := >=1.2.0 <1.3.0
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a wildcard character. Very common in Computer Science:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character

Comment: Yes - I know it is wildcard. ie It forces Bower to use the latest version or sub-version. However, my question particularly asked  where Bower derives the latest version or Sub Version. 

Is it based on Tag, Release or Commit.